# How do i update this command to v13 i tried multiple ways but did not succeed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

**I don't get any responce after the answer is sent.**
How do i fix it?

```
 const ws = require('../../configs/words.json');
    const word = ws[Math.floor(Math.random() * ws.length)];
    const filter = response => {
        return word.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
    };

    message.channel.send(word.question).then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 600000, errors: ['time'] })
            .then(collected => {
                message.reply(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer! + 1 tickets!`);
            })
            .catch(collected => {
                message.channel.send('Noone has guessed the word in time.');
            });
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked your intents?

Comment: It should work if you had the `GUILD` and `GUILD_MESSAGES` intents.

Comment: I do have those intents.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, its rebuilt a little but should function the same:

```js
const ws = require('../../configs/words.json');
const word = ws[Math.floor(Math.random() * ws.length)];
const filter = response => {
    return word.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
};

message.channel.send(word.question).then(() => {
    return message.channel.awaitMessages({
        filter,
        max: 1,
        time: 600000,
        errors: ['time']
    }).catch(() => {
        throw new Error('Timed Out')
    }).then(collected => {
        message.reply(`${collected.first().author} got the correct answer! + 1 tickets!`);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            switch (error.message) {
                case 'Timed Out':
                    message.channel.send('Noone has guessed the word in time.');
                break
        })
```

Comment: It did work! Yey thank you so much!!!